# Directional derivative of $f=f(\nabla \cdot\mathbf{u})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculus-of-variations

How do you evaluate the directional derivative of

$$f=f(\nabla \cdot\mathbf{u})\tag{1}$$

I've tried this but I'm not sure that my answer is correct, here is my attempt:

The definition of the directional derivative:

$$Df(\mathbf{u})[\mathbf{u^*}]=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{df(\mathbf{u}+\epsilon\mathbf{u^*})}{d\epsilon}\right]\tag{2}$$

**Attempt 1**

$$Df(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u})[\mathbf{u}^*]=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}^*\epsilon))}{d\epsilon}$$

By the chain rule:
$$=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{df(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}^*\epsilon))}{d(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}^*\epsilon))}\frac{d\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}^*\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}\right]$$

$$=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{df(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}^*\epsilon))}{d(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}^*\epsilon))}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}^*\right]$$

$$=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[f'(\nabla \cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}^*\epsilon))\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}^*\right]$$

$$=f'(\nabla \cdot\mathbf{u})\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}^*\tag{3}$$

**Attempt 2**

I really don't think this is right but the notation of the question I've been given (which is $(1)$) is confusing me:

$$Df(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u})[\mathbf{u}^*]=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{u})+\mathbf{u}^*\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}\tag{4}$$

$$=f'(\nabla \cdot\mathbf{u})\mathbf{u}^*\tag{5}$$

Are either of these attempts correct? And if not how do you derive the correct answer?

Comment: The directional derivative is usually a real-valued function, so your second answer is probably not right since you've written a vector.

Answer (score 0):

If $u: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a fixed vector-valued function, then define $g:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x,y,z)=\nabla \cdot u(x,y,z)$. Then $F(x,y,z)=f(\nabla \cdot u) = (f\circ g) (x,y,z)$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. The directional derivative of $F$ in the $v$-direction is denoted by $D_v F$ and is a real-valued function $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$D_v F(x,y,z) = D(F(x,y,z))(v) = D(f\circ g(x,y,z))(v)= [Df(g(x,y,z))\circ Dg(x,y,z)](v) = f'(g(x,y,z))[\nabla g(x,y,z) \cdot v] $$
Thus $D_v F(x,y,z) = f'(\nabla \cdot u)[\nabla(\nabla \cdot u) \cdot v]$

Comment: I don't understand how you get this $[Df(g(x,y,z))\circ Dg(x,y,z)](v)$ from the previous step? Could you explain how you prove that?

Comment: It is the chain rule for higher dimensional derivatives.

Comment: In that case should the $\circ$ be a $\times$?

Comment: When working with higher dimensional derivatives multiplication is not right; how would you multiply two vector valued functions? The inputs and outputs have to make sense as functions, so the correct generalization is function composition, not multiplication.

Comment: I don't understand what $Df(g(x,y,z))$ means on it's own without $[v]$ at the end, is it just $\nabla f$?

Comment: It's a function that's being composed with another function, as in $[Df(g(x,y,z))\circ Dg(x,y,z)](v)=Df(g(x,y,z))\left[Dg(x,y,z)(v)\right]$. You input $v$ into $Dg(x,y,z)$ and then plug that into $Df(g(x,y,z))$.